# Jenkins forbidden response to a SonarQube jsonp request

Tags: json, jenkins, sonarqube, http-status-code-403

I have installed Jenkins on my Ubuntu server by apt-get.

My Jenkins had [Secure Requester Whitelist Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Secure+Requester+Whitelist+Plugin).

So I can use javascript jsonp to access Jenkins json api on my localhost (different domain with Jenkins server) successfully.

The javascript code looks like this:

```html
p id="id"></p>
<script type="text/javascript">
function display(data){
 document.getElementById("id").innerHTML = data.number;
}

</script>
<script type="application/javascript" src="http://$myjenkinshost/job/$myjob/lastBuild/api/json?jsonp=display"> </script>
```

But after I added this javascript into my SonarQube plugin. The javascript can't access Jenkins json anymore.
The Jenkins responded the HTTP request with:

**[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (jsonp forbidden; implement jenkins.security.SecureRequester)**

But if I turnoff the Enable Security checkbox on Jenkins Configure Global Security setting,
the javascript in SonarQube plugin can access Jenkins json successfully.

Why Jenkins only disable SonarQube access json object?

Does Jenkins forbid  HTTP request with Referrer?

The HTTP request by SonarQube had referrer on http://localhost:9000.

Is there any setting on my Jenkins I can do to avoid the following error?
**[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (jsonp forbidden; implement jenkins.security.SecureRequester)**